# Long dynamic Oracle query and How to debug it

Tags: sql, oracle10g, dynamic-sql

I have a stored procedure that, I am currently working on which uses dynamic sql query.

It has one variable assigned to (5000 - 6000 characters of dynamic SQL) and another variable assigned to (5000 - 6000 characters of dynamic SQL)
and a UNION ALL between both the variables.

I got the dynamic query from the procedure and ran it on the editor. It returned me a row of data. How can I debug this query?

Can I do:

```
var1 = "dyamic SQL..." 
UNION ALL 
var2 = "dynamic SQL..."
```

Any advice to help me debug this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can do what you're trying to do. You will probably have to extract the dynamic SQL as a *real* query, fill in any substitution values, and then try running it in a query window.

Comment: What do you want to debug about it, other than checking its result? Stored procedures can be debugged. Queries are (to the outside) atomic operations.

Comment: I can try the approach suggested by FrustratedWithFormsDesigner the query is returning wrong result so I am trying to fix it, so that is what I mentioned by debugging it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run a dynamic query (if that is the term), but not in this way. You can execute a query string using

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'sqlstring'
```

or using

```
OPEN c FOR 'sqlstring'
```

and there is a package too that lets you execute a query with bound parameters.

But all these require that the query is a single string, so I'd suggest you put the two queries together in a third variable ...

```
var3 = var1 || ' UNION ALL ' || var2;
```

.. and then execute var3.

Comment: I will try this approach as well. Thanks Golez.